# IBOutletCollections and Interface Builder on OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have a `NSViewController` , in which I wish to create a an `IBOutletCollection(NSTextField)`.

In my header file, I introduced these lines of code :

```
@property (strong) IBOutletCollection(NSTextField) NSArray *iNetworkIDOctets;

@property (strong) IBOutletCollection(NSTextField) NSArray *oWildcardOctets;

@property (strong) IBOutletCollection(NSTextField) NSArray *oSubnetOctets;
```

My problem is that I can't see the IBOutletCollection in Interface Builder, therefore, I can't connect my NSTextField items to my outlet collection.

Normal `IBoutlet`properties work fine though.

[image][image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Unfortunately, IBOutletCollection is only supported on iOS. For OS X, you'll have to create a separate outlet for each object, or else come up with an alternate way to reference the text fields in your XIB.

Comment: Cool. It would've been awesome if Xcode actually gave us an error message.

Comment: Man, MacOS is completely at drift and poor compared to iOS. Even tvOS is superior in terms of API to interface control and Xcode is the worse piece of crap ever created. How can an IDE allow you to declare an IBOutletCollection on a Cocoa project without any warning?