# Cannot put multiple imageViews into one (array) outlet with swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode8, outlet

I am using OSX in Xcode 8 and swift. With storyboard, I have several NSImageViews (10) that I have dragged into an NSView.I need access to them all in the subclassed parent NSViewController I have read that one can put them in an array outlet but descriptions of how to do this differ with Xcode version and I have seen nothing that works. Here is the storyboard, showing two imageViews:
[image]

The code cannot be shown because it is just an outlet. Currently, I am trying to declare it as:

```
@IBOutlet var collectionOfViews: Array<NSImageView>?
```

Such an outlet, giving me an array, would be perfect.But I have no idea how to connect to the individual views. One poster (in the voluminous record) suggested that the popup for outlet creation would have a choice as an outlet array but that does not happen: I get either Outlet or Action ( do have a very hazy recollection of seeing array choice in Xcode 7, but I never used it). Another poster suggested to look at the connections inspector, where the array outlet would be choosable - I don't see it there either.

This should be a simple operation. Can anyone help me figure it out? I have exhausted the google searches, unfortunately.

Later Edit: I remember now where the outlet array worked. It was in my ios projects, where it shows up exactly as expected. Should I assume that it is just not implemented on osx?

Comment: Looks like outlet collections are indeed only supported on iOS projects. See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255693/iboutletcollections-and-interface-builder-on-osx).

Comment: Thanks...I didn't see that one. Good to have clarity.